# Error while installing scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, pip

i use python 3.6 , and when i try to install scrapy using pip on cmd the output was as shown here :

```
     Command ""c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import 
     setuptools, 
     tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Sarah\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-
     hql11prt\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
     (__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
     '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
     C:\Users\Sarah\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-b2cmfpf2-record\install-
     record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with 
     error code 1 in C:\Users\Sarah\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-
     hql11prt\Twisted\
```

how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Is there more to the output?

Comment: Try using `easy_install scrapy` and see if that helps?

Comment: i tried it but now i got this error :                                                                LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
error: Setup script exited with error: command failed with exit status 1158

Comment: @Avery yes but this is the error part of the output

Comment: Do you see any _"Not Found"_ errors above this?

Comment: warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bin'
no previously-included directories found matching 'admin'
no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'docs\historic\2003'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\historic\2003'
raiser.c

Comment: @AniMenon yes as I listed in the previous comment

Comment: @SaraMahmoud Post the full error(in the question); I think you maybe missing dependency packages.

Answer (score 0):

Download Twisted from the website below and install it first, and then `pip install scrapy`

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/